# What exactly is paragraph leading for indesign paragraph

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign, typography

I am working in an indesign script and I would like to know what exactly is `leading` for a paragraph as described in the documentation [Indesign Paragraph](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js/pc_Paragraph.html). Is that the height for each line in the paragraph?

Comment: Leading is a very basic concept in typography. Google it and the wikipedia article about it is one of the first results you will see

Comment: So is it  `font-size + spacing between lines` in indesign?

Comment: @slebetman: true for both your statements, but *not* true for Adobe InDesign. Then again, that same (generally very useful) search engine should have lead OP to the online help pages of Adobe InDesign in the first place. I see no need for Stack Overflow to contain a copy of everything that can be found *trivially*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Leading is the distance from one baseline to the next.

The leading of the top line can be anything because there's nothing above it to push it down.

Note: since fonts can vary in X-height and they allow space for descenders etc., they don't usually take up the full pixel dimension. In the following image, all the text is 100px and the height of the boxes surrounding the text is the same as the leading for each line.

[image]

Comment: So is from one baseline of a line to the next baseline?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu Yes.  The distance in pixes, points, inches, etc. from one baseline to the next.

Comment: so what would be the leading for the first line then?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu Sorry, I clarified my answer.  And the leading for the first line can be anything because there's nothing above it.

Comment: Can you post a sample image and explain the same?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208474/discussion-between-thingevery-and-sundeep-pidugu).

Comment: Can you please explain the attached image?